# Is there a way to check if ansicon.exe exists without running it using CMake?

Tags: windows, cmake, command, console-application

Most of the messages in my CMake project are colored. In Windows, the color only shows if the user has [`ansicon.exe`](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) downloaded, and prints a weird character otherwise. Therefore, I want to check if the command `ansicon` exists before attempting to color the messages.

I have tried to do it this way, hoping `WIN_COLOR` will tell me if the command exists:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND "ansicon"
    RESULT_VARIABLE WIN_COLOR
)
```

It does, but it actually runs `ansicon.exe`, which runs a new instance of the command prompt, effectively stopping the configuration process.

Is there a better way? Do I have to end up looking through directories?

Comment: Is `ansicon` in your path?

Comment: @octopod, why do you not accept Peter's answer?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [find_program](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:find_program)

```
find_program(WIN_COLOR "ansicon")
IF(WIN_COLOR)
   ...
ENDIF()
```

Comment: AFAIK it should be `if(NOT ${WIN_COLOR} STREQUAL WIN_COLOR-NOTFOUND)` on modern Cmake.